# Зачем в Java введена поддержка конвертация коллекции в Stream и функционал операций с ними? страдает производительность

Tags: java-stream, java-8

Только ради синтаксического сахара?

Comment: а на каком основании вы утверждаете что производительность падает? у вас есть тест демонстрирующий насколько падает производительность?

Answer (score 1):

Язык развивается, появляется возможность добавить в код процедурщины, многим программистам это необходимо, т.к. без стримов код порой выглядит довольно громоздко

Answer (score 1):

стримы оправданы в двух случаях:
1) для обработки больших объемов данных (десятки тысяч, сотни тысяч, миллионы элементов) с использованием возможности распараллеливания
2) если вы заморочились и натюнили jit-компиляцию в jvm, ибо на горячую jit-компилятор пытается стримы развернуть в циклы, но получается у него это не всегда

во всех остальных случаях вы правы - производительность падает, а по поводу краткости и выразительности стримов еще можно поспорить, в большинстве случаев (ИМХО) при переписывании кода со стримов на циклы, он становился более кратким, понятным и производительным